# How to efficiently see if element is in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

Perhaps this has been asked before, but I keep having this problem and I wanted to know how this can be done most efficiently

**The question is: How do you efficiently check if an element is in a list of tuples?**

---

I have a list of tuples--named 'categories'--which takes in a tuple consisting of a category name and a number for the category.

I want to find if the category name a user inputs is actually a category inside of this list of tuples.

For example:

```
categories = [('Exam', 15), ('Homework', 20)]
```

Now the program asks the user for an category input:

```
user_category_input = input('Please enter a category name: ')
user_category_input = user_category_input.strip()
```

Now, I want the program to check and see if the user input for category name is actually a category in the list of tuples. If the user inputs "Exam", obviously, it is true! "Exam" is a category in the list of tuples. If it is "Presentations" then it is false etc.

The simple solution I have been using is to simply iterate through the tuples and check if the first element equals user input as this  code shows:

```
for category in categories:
   if category[0] == user_category_input:
      return True

return False
```

But is this the most efficient way?

Is it possible to use some sort of lambda here?
Does it make a difference to make it more efficient here?

Still learning python and just trying to see what should be done in practice so sorry if this is redundant or just a silly question :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any()`

```
return any(c[0] == user_category_input for c in categories)
```

But if you need to do this frequently, it would be better to make `categories` a dictionary instead of a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Make it into a `dict`. It is the appropriate data type to use for this data:

```
>>> dict(categories)
{'Exam': 15, 'Homework': 20}
```

---

```
categories = {'Exam': 15, 'Homework': 20}
return user_category_input in categories
```

If it must remain a `list` of `tuple`s you could make a `set` of each category using `zip`:

```
cats = set(next(zip(*categories))
{'Exam', 'Homework'}
```

Then check for membership:

```
return user_category_input in cats
```